# Android, VPN, Asterisk communication

Tags: android, voip, vpn, asterisk, nat

I'm trying to write a voip app for Android, using the Android SIP API (Yes, I know this only works with some Androids with version 2.3). I want calls to be routed through an Asterisk server. The calls also need to be encrypted. A problem exists where Asterisk and the Androids need to be on the same subnet (otherwise no audio is exchanged). There is a nice blog post I found at http://blog.harritronics.com/2011/06/android-gingerbread-and-asterisk-pbx.html describing the situation for those that are curious.

I'm looking to setup a VPN solution as discussed in the article as I figure this could solve the NAT issue, along with encryption. My first thought was to use OpenVPN since there is a pretty active community and the software looks pretty nice. However, after further inspection, it seems that I can only have 2 clients active on the VPN server at any given time (for the free version). Each additional client connection is $5. In short, I'm wondering if a scalable free solution exists. I would like to be able to connect somewhere around 100 android phones to this VPN to communicate with Asterisk simultaneously.

Also, I have done no VPN work previously. I'm wondering can I simply use the VPN configuration within the Android Settings? Or does there need to be an additional application? I saw that OpenVPN had a client solution for Android that only worked if the phone was rooted - this is not an option, as they are not my phones. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you've been looking at, but OpenVPN certainly does not have any restrictions on the number of clients. Anyway, as you have found out, OpenVPN is not supported by the default Android distribution, though it is integrated in CyanogenMod. Android also has a built-in VPN client however, so you just need to find a server that works with that. As of 4.0 (ICS) it is also possible to write your own VPN implementation without rooting the phone.

BTW, the audio problem only arises if the phones are NAT-ed (e.g., connected via WiFi to your internal router, etc.). If the have global addresses, there should be no problem. If you connect over 3G that would depend on whether your carrier gives phones actual global addresses.

Another alternative is not to the Android SIP stack. There are other solutions available, and they might not have this restriction. Check sipdroid, it open source:

http://sipdroid.org/

Yet another alternative is to not try to write your own app, just use sipdroid :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. My original thought was that it would be completely free, until I saw the pricing at http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/pricing.html. Is it possible to use the built-in Android VPN client with an OpenVPN server? I am currently focusing on Android 2.3, not 4.0. The audio issue is a real one, since most of the phones will be NAT-ed behind a router with internal IPs.

Comment: This is a commercial offering based on the open source software: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html. Practically every distribution has packages, or you could compile it yourself. You do not need to buy the commercial version.There are ways to get around the NAT issue with Asterisk, you don't necessarily need a VPN. You could have dual-homed Asterisk proxy, there are routes with SIP support, etc. You probably need to evaluate more options and find the one that fits best. Getting VPN to work reliably on 100 android devices may not be that easy, and is surely hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the nat=yes option of Asterix I only think in one more solution. That nat option worked for me behind a router but I know that it isn't a very "inteligent" NAT traversing from Asterisk, it needs "colaboration" from the client too. The other solution could be... when I was working with that, I was using CSipSimple, it's an open source voip client for Android, may be you can look at the sources and find why that traverses works behind a router doing NAT.

If you're looking just for an **[Android VPN client](http://vpnandroid.net/android-vpn-clients/)**, there are some of them, at least one with a 100% free option.

Hope that helps!